# how to solve "The back button(Esc button) is not working properly" issue

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

the back button on 1st load does not work on singin_screen but it works on option_screen(on 1st load) and after that if choose any option from options and go to that option's screen and and then come back to option screen the back does not work, It doesn't do anything

```
sign_screen(back closes the app)

      --> option_screen(back button works on 1st load but not after that)

             --> body_screen
             --> RemoveStock_screen
             --> Stoploss_ip
             (on these three screens there no problem with back button it works fine)
```

**.py code**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.gridlayout import MDGridLayout
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
import sys, time, threading
import pyrebase
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
import pandas as pd
from kivymd.icon_definitions import md_icons
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex
import webbrowser
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList,ThreeLineListItem,ThreeLineAvatarIconListItem,OneLineListItem
from kivymd.uix.list import IconLeftWidget,ImageLeftWidget
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCardSwipe
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
import csv
from os import path
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ListProperty, BooleanProperty, ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import re
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
import pandas as pd
from kivy.clock import Clock
from functools import partial
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField,MDTextFieldRound
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.toast import toast
from kivy.core.window import Window
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

username =''

fg = BooleanProperty(False)


class Signin(MDScreen):
    user_name = ObjectProperty(None)

    def hook_keyboard(self, Window, key, *largs):
        if key == 27:
            button_yes = MDFlatButton(text="Yes", text_color=(98 / 255, 0, 238 / 255, 1),
                                      on_press=self.quit_appp)
            button_No = MDFlatButton(text="No", text_color=(98 / 255, 0, 238 / 255, 1),
                                     on_press=self.close_dialog1)
            self.signin_dialog = MDDialog(title='Are you sure?', text="This action will close the App",
                                          size_hint=(.9, .5), buttons=[button_No, button_yes])
            self.signin_dialog.open()
        return True

    def quit_appp(self, dl):
        run1().stop()

    def open_link(instance, link):

        webbrowser.open(link)

    def build(self):
        Window.bind(on_keyboard=self.hook_keyboard)

    def check(self, email):
        regex = '^[a-z0-9]+[\._]?[a-z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]\w{2,3}$'
        # pass the regular expression
        # and the string in search() method
        if (re.search(regex, email)):
            return True

        else:
            return False

    def btn(self):
        global username
        global fg
        un = self.user_name.text
        if self.check(un):
            username, u = un.split('@')
            print(username)
            fg = True

            threading.Thread(target=self.check_fb_file()).start()
        else:
            button_ok = MDFlatButton(text="Ok", text_color=(98 / 255, 0, 238 / 255, 1),
                                     on_press=self.close_dialog)
            self.signin_dialog = MDDialog(title='Error', text="That doesn't appear to be a valid email address",
                                          size_hint=(.9, .5), buttons=[button_ok])
            self.signin_dialog.open()

    def check_fb_file(self):
        # down = Firebaseupdown()
        # down.fire_download()
        self.user_name.text = ''
        MDApp.get_running_app().root.transition.direction = 'left'
        MDApp.get_running_app().root.current = 'option_screen'
        # self.popup.dismiss()

    def close_dialog(self, obj):
        self.signin_dialog.dismiss()
        self.user_name.text = ''

    def close_dialog1(self, obj):
        self.dialog.dismiss()


counter = 1


class Option(MDScreen):
    global username
    flag_dis = BooleanProperty(False)

    def hook_keyboard(self, Window, key, *largs):
        if key == 27:
            self.back()
        return True

    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        global counter

        Window.bind(on_keyboard=self.hook_keyboard)
        file_name = username + "_stoploss.csv"
        if path.exists(file_name) and counter == 1:
            toast("The data has been synchronized with cloud")
            counter += 1

        elif not path.exists(file_name):
            self.flag_dis = True
            toast('Please Go to Add Stock')
        else:
            self.flag_dis = False
            print('All good')
            pass

    def back(self):
        MDApp.get_running_app().root.transition.direction = 'right'
        MDApp.get_running_app().root.current = 'signin_screen'

class Body(MDScreen):
    def back(self):

        MDApp.get_running_app().root.transition.direction = 'right'
        MDApp.get_running_app().root.current = 'option_screen'

    def hook_keyboard(self, Window, key, *largs):
        if key == 27:
            self.back()
        return True

    def on_pre_enter(self):
        Window.bind(on_keyboard=self.hook_keyboard)
    def back(self):
        MDApp.get_running_app().root.transition.direction = 'right'
        MDApp.get_running_app().root.current = 'option_screen'
class Remove_stock(MDScreen):
    def hook_keyboard(self, Window, key, *largs):
        if key == 27:
            self.back()
        return True

    def build(self):
        Window.bind(on_keyboard=self.hook_keyboard)
    def back(self):
        MDApp.get_running_app().root.transition.direction = 'right'
        MDApp.get_running_app().root.current = 'option_screen'
class ListApp(MDScreen):
    def hook_keyboard(self, Window, key, *largs):
        if key == 27:
            self.back()
        return True

    def build(self):
        Window.bind(on_keyboard=self.hook_keyboard)

    def back(self):
        MDApp.get_running_app().root.transition.direction = 'right'
        MDApp.get_running_app().root.current = 'option_screen'

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Signin(name='signin_screen'))
sm.add_widget(Option(name='option_screen'))
sm.add_widget(ListApp(name='Stoploss_ip'))
sm.add_widget(Body(name='body_screen'))
sm.add_widget(Remove_stock(name='RemoveStock_screen'))


class run1(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_file("min.kv")
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run1().run()
```

**.kv code**

```
    ScreenManager:
    Signin:

    Option:
    Body:
        id:body
    Remove_stock:
    ListApp:


<Remove_stock>:
    name: 'RemoveStock_screen'
    on_enter:root.build()
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing: "10dp"

        MDToolbar:
            title:'List of shares'
            type: "top"
            size_hint_y:0.1
            pos_hint: {'top':1.0}
            left_action_items: [["arrow-left", lambda x: root.back()]]
            md_bg_color:152/255,87/255,189/255,1
            elevation:10


        ScrollView:

            scroll_type:["content"]

            MDList:
                id: md_list
                padding: 0
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
                MDLabel:
                    text:'I am Remove_stock'
                    halign:'center'

<Body>:
    name: 'body_screen'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 155/255, 159/255, 250/255, 1

        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    MDLabel:
        text:"I am Body class"
        halign:'center'

<Signin>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 239/255, 235/255, 216/255, 1

        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    name: 'signin_screen'
    user_name: user_name

    orientation:'vertical'
    MDTextField:

        id: user_name
        hint_text:'Email'

        icon_right: "email"
        icon_right_color:0,0,0,1
        required: True

        color_active: 0, 0, 0, 1
        helper_text: "Invalid email id"
        helper_text_mode: "on_error"
        halign:'center'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        size_hint_x: 0.9
        width:300
        color_mode: 'custom'

        line_color_normal: 0,0,0,1


    MDRoundFlatIconButton:
        icon: "arrow-right"
        text:"Submit"
        text_color:1,1,1,1
        font_size: 20
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .4}
        halign:'center'
        md_bg_color:36/255,76/255,100/255,1
        elevation:10




        background_color: (1,1,1,1)
        on_press :
            root.btn()
    NavigationLayout:
        ScreenManager:

            Screen:

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    MDToolbar:
                        title:'SignIn'
                        type: "top"
                        size_hint_y:0.1
                        pos_hint: {'top':1.0}
                        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.toggle_nav_drawer()]]
                        right_action_items: [["exit-to-app", lambda x: app.stop()]]
                        md_bg_color:152/255,87/255,189/255,1
                        elevation:10
                    Widget:
        MDNavigationDrawer:

            id: nav_drawer

            MDBoxLayout:
                canvas.before:
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                        source: 'crop1.jpg'
                orientation:'vertical'
                spacing: '10dp'
                padding: '10dp'
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
                MDLabel:
                    text:'Developer'
                    bold: True
                    user_font_size: "20dp"
                    theme_text_color: "Custom"
                    text_color: 1, 0, .5, 1
                    halign:'center'
                    size_hint_y:None
                    height: 20
                MDFloatingActionButton:
                    icon:'me.png'
                    elevation:12
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5,'center_y': .8}
                    user_font_size: "20dp"
                MDLabel:
                    size_hint_y:None
                    height: 10
                MDLabel:
                    text:'Rushabh Patil'
                    font_style:'Subtitle1'
                    theme_text_color: "Custom"
                    text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                    bold: True
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
                    size_hint_y:None
                    height: self.texture_size[1]
                    halign:'center'

                MDLabel:
                    text:'rushabhpatil.rdp@gmail.com'
                    font_style:'Caption'
                    bold: True
                    theme_text_color: "Custom"
                    text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                    size_hint_y:None
                    height: self.texture_size[1]
                    halign:'center'
                MDLabel:
                    size_hint_y:None
                    height: 230

                ScrollView:

                    MDList:

                        OneLineIconListItem:

                            text:'Github Profile'
                            theme_text_color: "Custom"
                            text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                            bold: True
                            on_press: root.open_link('https://github.com/rushbhpatil')
                            IconLeftWidget:

                                icon:"Github-icon.png"
                                user_font_size: "7dp"
                                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}

                        MDLabel:
                            size_hint_y:None
                            height: 60
                        OneLineIconListItem:

                            text:'Linkedin Profile'
                            theme_text_color: "Custom"
                            text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                            bold: True
                            on_press: root.open_link('https://www.linkedin.com/in/rushbh-patil-77313062/')
                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon:'Linkedin-icon.png'
                                user_font_size: "7dp"
                                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
                MDCard:
                    md_bg_color:0, 0, 0, 0
                    orientation:'vertical'
                    size_hint:None,None
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .1}
                    height:100
                    width:80
                    elevation:0



                    MDLabel:
                        text:'Made For'
                        theme_text_color: "Custom"
                        text_color:176/255,176/255,176/255,1
                        font_size: "9dp"
                        pos_hint: {'center_x': .55, 'center_y': .5}

                        halign:'center'
                        size_hint:1,None
                        height:10
                    MDIconButton:
                        md_bg_color:0, 0, 0, 0
                        icon: "absys_logo.png"
                        user_font_size: "18dp"
                        halign:'center'
                        size_hint:None,None
                        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}

<Option>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 138/255,43/255,226/255,.4
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    name: 'option_screen'

    orientation:'vertical'
    spacing: '20dp'

#    on_enter:root.build()
    MDToolbar:
        title:'Choose Option'
        type: "top"
        md_bg_color:152/255,87/255,189/255,1
        left_action_items: [["arrow-left", lambda x: root.back()]]
        size_hint_y:0.1
        pos_hint: {'top':1.0}
        elevation:10


    MDCard:
        md_bg_color:138/255,43/255,226/255,1
        orientation:'vertical'
        size_hint:None,None
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .74}
        height:110
        width:60
        elevation:8


        MDIconButton:
            md_bg_color:138/255,43/255,226/255,1
            icon: "beaker-plus"
            user_font_size: "40dp"
            halign:'center'
            size_hint:None,None
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .6}
            elevation:6
            on_press :

                root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                root.manager.current = 'body_screen'

        MDLabel:
            text:'Add Stock'
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color:1,1,1,1
            font_size: "15dp"
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .4}
            halign:'center'


    MDCard:
        md_bg_color:138/255,43/255,226/255,1
        orientation:'vertical'
        size_hint:None,None
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .454}
        height:110
        width:60
        elevation:8


        MDIconButton:
            md_bg_color:138/255,43/255,226/255,1
            icon: "beaker-minus"
            user_font_size: "40dp"
            halign:'center'
            size_hint:None,None
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .6}
#            disabled : True if root.flag_dis==True else False
            on_press :

                root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                root.manager.current = 'RemoveStock_screen'

        MDLabel:
            text:'Remove Stock'
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color:1,1,1,1
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .4}
            font_size: "15dp"
            halign:'center'


    MDCard:
        md_bg_color:138/255,43/255,226/255,1
        orientation:'vertical'
        size_hint:None,None
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .17}
        height:110
        width:60
        elevation:8

        MDIconButton:
            icon: "check"
            user_font_size: "40dp"
            halign:'center'
            size_hint:None,None
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .6}
#            disabled : False if root.flag_dis==False else True
            on_press :
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                root.manager.current = 'Stoploss_ip'

        MDLabel:
            text:'Check Stoploss'
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color:1,1,1,1
            font_size: "15dp"
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .4}
            halign:'center'


<ListApp>:
    name: 'Stoploss_ip'

    on_enter:root.build()
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        MDToolbar:
            title:'Stoploss'
            type: "top"
            md_bg_color:152/255,87/255,189/255,1
            left_action_items: [["arrow-left", lambda x: root.back()]]
#            right_action_items: [["reload", lambda x: root.update()]]
            size_hint_y:0.1
            pos_hint: {'top':1.0}
            elevation:10

        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                id: list_view
                pos_hint: {'y':3.0}
                MDLabel:
                    text:'I am ListApp'
                    halign:'center'
```

after login the option screen open and you press Esc key it comes back to signin_screen but on sign screen the Esc is not working

but if you do not press Esc and choose any option outof three the next screen opens and when you press Esc it comes back to option_screen

and now the option_screen is loaded 2nd time and if I press Esc it doesnot work
also if want to go back to signin_screen click on back_arrow in toolbar..`it takes you to signin_screen.. but when you press Esc on signin_screen now it will take you to option_screen directly`

every time it is behaving differently

Comment: Is `android` tag relevant here?

Comment: Post a minimal runnable example. If the back button is behaving differently on different screens, it's presumably something in your code that we can't guess at.

Comment: @inclement   I have updated the with the minimal runnable example.. please take a look